# Vue JS + Firebase message system

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My web application checks if user has messages in firebase database. If so, it gets the data from users that have sent the messages in my local database and display them in a list with `v-for` loop.

The data is profile image, name, last name and city. Below this data a message box is displayed for each user to display their messages from firebase.

This all works fine. My problem is that when I get the messages from FB only the last user messages are displayed for all users:

[image]

As you can see user `uid = 2` has 3 messages and user `uid = 3` has one message. But I can display only user `uid = 3` messages in all message boxes.

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            memberData: {},
            myMessages: [],
            memberMessages: [],
            myID: userID,
            messages: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() { },
    created: function () {
        this.getAllMessages();
    },
    methods: {
        scrollBox: function () {
            let messagebox = document.querySelector('#messages-container');
            messagebox.scrollTop = messagebox.scrollHeight;
        },
        getAllMessages: function () {
            console.log(this.myID);
            let distinct = '';

            firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages')
            .where('memberID', '==', `${this.myID}`)
            .orderBy('date')
            .onSnapshot(res => {

                let members = [];
                res.forEach(doc => {
                    members.push(doc.data().uid);
                });
                distinct = Array.from(new Set(members));
                // console.log(distinct);
                
                this.getUserToTalk(distinct);
            });
        },
        getMessages: function(memberID){

            // console.log(memberID);

            firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages').where('uid', '==', `${memberID}`).orderBy('date')
            .onSnapshot(res => {
                let messages = [];
                res.forEach(doc => {
                    messages.push(doc.data());
                });
                this.memberMessages = messages;
                console.log(this.memberMessages);
            });
        },
        getUserToTalk: function (memberID) {
            // console.log(memberID);
            axios.post('http://localhost/backend/getMemberToTalk.php', {
                "token": token,
                "whoToTalkTo": memberID
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.data != "Error getting user data") {
                    this.memberData = response.data;
                    this.memberData.forEach(res => {
                        let id = res.memberID;
                        // console.log(id);
                        this.getMessages(id);
                    });
                    // console.log(this.memberData);
                } else {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        sendMessage: function (memberID) {
            $('#messages_form').on('submit', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let message = this.messages;

                if (!message.trim()) return;
                console.log(message);
                this.messages = '';

                console.log(memberID);
                ...
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
});
```

html:

```
<div id="app" class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row messages-row" v-for="(item, index) in memberData" :key="index">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                <div class="messages-profile-infos">
                    <div class="messages-profile-infos-img img-fluid"
                        v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/backend/clients/'+item.memberProfileImg + ')' }">
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages-profile-infos-text">
                        <p>{{ item.memberName }} {{ item.memberLastname }}</p>
                        <p>{{ item.memberCity }} - {{ item.memberState }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-12">
                <div class="messages-btns">
                    <button class="btn trade-btn" onclick="showConversation()">Messages</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- conversation box -->
            <div class="conversation-container">
                <div id="messages-container" class="messages-container" :key="item.memberID">
                    <!-- <div v-for="message in allMessages" class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ message.message }}</span>
                    </div> -->

                    <!-- actually testing with this one -->
                    <div v-if="item.memberID == message.uid" v-for="message in memberMessages" class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ message.message }}</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <div v-for="message in myMessages" class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">{{ message.message }}</span>
                    </div> -->

                    <!-- <div v-for="message in myMessages" class="d-flex" :class="[message.uid != myID ?'justify-content-start':'justify-content-end']">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill" :class="[message.uid != myID ?'badge-primary':'badge-secondary']">{{ message.message }}</span>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="message-typing-container">
                    <form id="messages_form" action="" method="POST">
                        <div class="typing-container">
                            <input id="message" v-model="messages" type="text" class="message-typing" autocomplete="off" />
                            <input class="send-message" type="submit" value="Send" @click="sendMessage(item.memberID)" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
</div>
```

Is it possible to display each message to its corresponding user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've changed my approach. I get user data from my database like I said in my question and then I "attach" the messages from FB to their corresponding user:

```
getMessages: function(memberID){

        let messages = [];
        firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages').where('uid', '==', `${memberID}`).orderBy('date')
        .onSnapshot(res => {
            res.forEach(doc => {
                messages.push(doc.data());
            });
            
        });
        
        this.memberMessages = messages;
        return messages;
},
getUserToTalk: function (memberID) {
        axios.post('http://localhost/backend/getMemberToTalk.php', {
            "token": token,
            "whoToTalkTo": memberID
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.data != "Error getting user data and tour" && response.data != "Error receiving data") {
                
                let joinedData = []
                console.log(response.data);
                response.data.forEach(res => {
                    let id = res.memberID;
                    // console.log(id);
                    let messages = this.getMessages(id);
                    // console.log(messages);

                    let data = {
                        memberID: res.memberID,
                        memberProfileImg: res.memberProfileImg,
                        memberName: res.memberName,
                        memberLastname: res.memberLastname,
                        memberCity: res.memberCity,
                        memberState: res.memberState,
                        messages: messages
                    }
                    joinedData.push(data);
                    // console.log(data.messages);
                });
                this.memberData = joinedData;
                console.log(this.memberData);
            } else {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

html:

```
<div v-if="item.memberID == message.uid" v-for="message in item.messages" class="d-flex justify-content-start">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ message.message }}</span>
</div>
```